# Can you screw something that will not loosen?

Tags: wood, walls

I'm working on a wall hook project that is meant to be permanent (so once you install it you don't have to take it off the wall because of loose hooks or knobs - used for hanging keys or coats).

One thing is, the backing of the wall hook should be flat (so screwing would be inset).

I'm a laymen about this stuff. So would you use a bolt to lock the screw in or are there other options?

Comment: Sorry but I'm completely baffled by what you are trying to do, other than put something on the wall to hold coats and keys. But in my experience I've used ordinary cup hooks that are screwed into the base of a cabinet without them ever pulling out. And, as to hanging coats, I've bought wood pegs for coats, drilled holes, and glued them in without any looseness. Pictures or a sketch would help us help you more.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking "How can permanently anchor a screw so it doesn't back out on it's own?"

If that's the case, adding glue to threads before screwing is likely the best bet. Epoxy would be the strongest, but for holding keys, likely overkill. Wood glue would probably be sufficient.